# Треугольники в HTML

Tags: html

Как сделать ссылками эти треугольники в сортировочном списке в HTML?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://unicode-table.com/ru/25BC/  вот так делаются, кроссбраузерно

Comment: вот так можно: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/LYbbYyW